# How to reference this preloaded image

Tags: javascript, image, preload

How would I reference an image preloaded from this javascript?  This code comes from the question at

stackoverflow: [[preload hidden CSS images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787319/preload-hidden-css-images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787319/preload-hidden-css-images)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function preloader() 
{
 // create object
 imageObj = new Image();

 // set image list
 images = new Array();
 images[0]="image1.jpg"

 imageObj.src=images[0];
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a logical error in your code as pointed out by Matt H.

Instead creating a separate `Image` object for each individual images. You are just creating one object and keep changing the `src` of that object.

```
function preloader() {
    // counter
    var i = 0;

    // set image list
    images = new Array();
    images[0] = "image1.jpg"
    images[1] = "image2.jpg"
    images[2] = "image3.jpg"
    images[3] = "image4.jpg"

    //create an array to hold all the Image objects
    imageObjs = [];

    // start preloading
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        var imageObj = new Image(); //create new Image object for each image
        imageObj.src = images[i]; //set the src of new Image object to current image
        imageObjs.push(imageObj); //add the current Image object to the array
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, but how is it referenced in the page, outside of the script.

Comment: @TravisJ: Since `imageObjs` is global variable, you can access each element by `imageObjs[0]`, `imageObjs[1]`, ...

Comment: or in js: document.getElementById("im").src = imageObjs[0].src?  Are these ways of referencing the imageObject and having them display on the page?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are depending on the browser cache as the "preloader". Only the last `images[i]` source is actually held in the `imageObj` variable. Just setting the `src` value of an image will pull it from the browser cache.

A proper method of preload would be to create an array of `imageObj` image objects. You still reference through `.src', but now you have image objects in Javascript memory rather than the browser cache.

Comment: a) Not my code, it is from another question. b) Although the code was not optimized the imageObj still held 1 preloaded image. c) That image could be referenced to be displayed in page based on the preloading.  - I have simplified the code so that *maybe* you can try to edit your answer to something more useful.