# Automatically loading a series of images sequentially in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a html page that gets automatically refreshed every 1 ms. I did it using mata tag:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>My Page</title>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.001">
   </head>

   <body>
     <img src=" 0.bmp" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="200" />
   </body>
 </html>
```

Now my requirement is such that after every refresh I must load a new file. So in my folder I have files named: 0.bmp, 1.bmp, 2.bmp,... 1000.bmp, which will be loaded on the html file. i.e after every refresh a new file from the folder will be loaded. Basically the file name in

```
   <img src=" 0.bmp" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="200" />
```

will change from 0.bmp to 1...1000.bmp and so on.

How can we do this in html i.e change the file name dynamically?

**Edited #1:**

I have just realized that my problem is basically of animation. So given 1000 images stored in hard disk, I have to play them one by one on an HTML page.  This should be as fast as possible. The only requirement is it must be on html pages, this is because these HTML pages will be accessed from a client in a network. the problem that I am thinking is slow playback because read/write to the disk may not be fast.

**Edited # 2**

After getting inputs from following answers, I was able to animate the images. The issue right now I am facing is the display rate is too small, and so fluctuations are coming up. I understand this is a problem of slow read/write from hard disk. So I guess if I can put these images in buffer i.e: System RAM, and write a html/js code to access the images from the RAM instead of the disk, the play back will be much faster.  Can someone send me a sample code to, write images in RAM and use html/js code to access these images from RAM?

Note: as per the policy of stackoverflow, I am updating my question as and when I am solving various steps of the original problem.

Comment: Your gonna need javascript i would imagine

Comment: I will appreciate if you could give me some hints or sample code for javascript.

Comment: As a practical matter no timer in Windows can tick as fast as 1ms. The fastest you would realistically see, depending on hardware is 12ms. After that is the fact that a browser will not be able to render a page in less than 1ms. So if the customer requires the browser refresh a page faster than 1 millisecond (i.e. 1000 frames per second): he's gonna have a bad time. Not even a DirectX powered media player can deliver 1000 frames per second. Finally, his monitor can only redraw every 16ms (i.e. 60 Hz). In short: your customer is a numb-skull who needs a smack.

Comment: I have updated my answer below based on your edit.  Your edit is now an entirely different question. It is hard to tell if you actually have a requirement to refresh the page or your requirement is to animate some sequences of images without refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updating my answer based on a now different question.

You can use this plugin: https://code.google.com/p/jsmovie/  It does exactly what you want by animating a set of images.

**Original Answer Below:**

Although I'd agree with many of the other answers, it seems the OP needs to refresh the entire window instead of doing this via ajax without a page reload.

```
<img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="200" style="display:none" />


function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var imgIndex = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    if (getParameterByName("index")!='') {
       imgIndex = parseInt(getParameterByName("index"));
    }

$('img').attr('src', imgIndex + '.bmp').show();

   var refreshId = setInterval( function()
    {

      imgIndex++;
      location.href = location.pathname + "?index=" + encodeURIComponent(imgIndex); 

    }, 1000); // 1 second update as needed

});
```

The following fiddle demonstrates this though I dont' have a serial set of images so the jsfiddle is a little different in that it updates an index of already set images forked from a previous answer but it does demonstrate the page reload.

http://jsfiddle.net/smf9w/1/

​

Comment: The issue now I am facing is the display rate is too slow. This is because I am reading the images from Hard disk. Is there a way I can put these images in buffer i.e RAM, and my html/js code access these images from RAM and display. This will be much faster. Can you please explain how this buffering can be done.

Comment: You could possibly preload the images.  See this question/answer about preloading images.  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787319/preload-hidden-css-images>  Realistically as other answers have indicated you will run into browser limits and probably won't be able to get true video frame rates.

Comment: I'd appreciate you marking one of the answers that helped you whether mine or otherwise.  If you have other questions those should be different questions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do should not be done by refreshing continuously the web page, but by the use of Javascript.

Consider this method using [JQUERY](http://jquery.com/) and [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval):

See a working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/uQbZf/)

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="path_to_image_01.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="128" width="128" />
    <img src="path_to_image_02.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="128" width="128" />
    <img src="path_to_image_03.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="128" width="128" />
    <img src="path_to_image_04.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="128" width="128" />
     </body>
 </html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img:not(:first)').hide();

  var refreshId = setInterval( function()
  {
    var $target = $('body img:first');
    $target.hide().next().show();
    $target.appendTo('body');
  }, 1000);
});
```

### What's being done

Hide all images

```
`$('img:not(:first)').hide();`
```

Initialize an interval of 1 sec that will collect the first image,
   hide it, jump to the next image, show it, lastly  move the previous
   image to the end.

```
var refreshId = setInterval( function()
{
  var $target = $('body img:first');
  $target.hide().next().show();
  $target.appendTo('body');
}, 1000);
```

This keeps on going animating the images every second that passes.

Comment: Great!! but can you tell me what this line is doing : r = (-0.5)+(Math.random()*(1000.99))? Also this r is not being used anywhere in the program.

Comment: also the link for setInterval() is giving error: "500 - Internal server error".

Comment: Sorry about that, it was from one function of mine! I've removed the line, it is not needed! Also, updated the setInterval link to other resource.

Comment: In general I like this solution because it is simple but if he has 1000 images it probably isn't the best of ideas to put them all on the page. One last thing, I think this might be an improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Zk2Ar/2/

Answer (score 1):

DON'T, really DON'T do this!!
Use JS instead. Use `setInterval()` and use a time span greater than 1m...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But actually I have a 'requirement' that I must refresh the browser very 1 ms.

Comment: 1ms isn't long enough for the content to be brought from the server. The system will fail. You should look at loading all the images and then showing them 1 at a time every 1ms.

Comment: @Sam My original question is not about the interval. It is about changing the file name after every refresh (lets say after every 10 seconds)

Comment: @gpuguy and what would this requirement be?

Comment: @kuh-chan i am simulating a physical process, where I want to display images in succession at about 1 ms.

Answer (score 0):

As others say, this is not the way to do it. But you can use cookie or localstorage on modern browsers.

```
  function getData() {
    var c = 0;
    if ("localStorage" in window && null !== window.localStorage)
       c = localStorage.count;
    else {
      count = document.cookie.split("count=");
      c = c[1].split(";");
      c = c[0];
    }
    return c;
 }

    function updateData(count){
       if ("localStorage" in window && null !== window.localStorage)
           localStorage.count = count;
        else {
            var e = new Date;
            e.setTime(e.getTime() + 31536E6);
            e = e.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = "count=" + count + "; expires=" + e + "; path=/"
        }
    }
 var count = getData();
 document.write('<img src="'+ count +'".bmp" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="200" />');
 updateData(++count);
```

Code above is just a sample.